# Can I contribute a full Nx executor for the Serverless framework?

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, nrwl

I'm currently working on a full support for the Serverless Framework Nx executor, and I have 2 options.

1. Publish it as a community standalone package
2. Contirbute to your Repository directly

To clarify my intentions - I'm working on a full supported executor, not a case-specific support.

Do you have other options I didn't mention?

Thanks,
Ofri

As I mentioned, I'm working on a full executor, my expectation is to hear the team and decide on the best path possible to ensure people can use it, because currently the community developement don't work well and require many manually adjustments, plus they don't support the full Serverless framework CLI.